# Xml-Serialization is not working

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

my XML-Serialization is not working.

The following code throws an exception:

```
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GeneralSettings));
```

I guess something is wrong with my GeneralSettings class? I can't figure out what the problem is exactly.

Class which shall be serialized:

```
[Serializable()]
class GeneralSettings
{
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------//
    #region Properties for settings
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------//
    public string ActiveLanguage { get; set; }

    public string ActiveLeague { get; set; }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------//
    #endregion
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------//

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------//
    #region Constructors
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------//

    public GeneralSettings()
    {
        this.ActiveLanguage = "English";
        this.ActiveLeague = "";
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------//
    #endregion
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------//
}
```

My BaseSettings Class to Serialize and deserialize

```
class BaseSettings
{
    protected static string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Settings\XML\GeneralSettings.xml");
        }
    }

    public static GeneralSettings Load()
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return (GeneralSettings)new XmlSerializer(typeof(GeneralSettings)).Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    public static void Save(GeneralSettings settings)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GeneralSettings));
            x.Serialize(stream, settings);
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class has to be public in order to be serializable via the `XmlSerializer` class.

Change the definition of the class to this:

```
public class GeneralSettings
{

    ...

}
```

Comment: +1. This is something he should have seen when running the code; as it'd give him an error like `GeneralSettings is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed.`

Comment: Okay this was easy, thanks! I will accept this answer as soon as i can